# Fabric Answer crash iOS app on start with Xcode 10 and iOS 12

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, google-fabric, xcode10

**EDIT**:

> Xcode 10 beta 6 fix the problem

---

I'm updating my app for ios 12 with the new xcode 10, but the Fabric framework makes the app crash at start.

I only run the code and the app crash on the launch screen.

In my AppDelegate:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Answers/Answers.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [Fabric with:@[[Answers class]]];

   return YES;
}
```

And this is the log that appear:

```
+[NSRecursiveLock dictionary]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x233a30580
(lldb)
```

I also added this writing as mentioned in the guide:
[image: Screenshot of Build Phase in Xcode 10]

And this is in the AppDelegate.m
[image: Breakpoint]

And this is the crash log

> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x00000001fa545104
>   **pthread_kill + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001fa5c4a00 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 296 2
>
>   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00000001fa49cd78 abort + 140 3
>
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00000001f9b64f78 __cxa_bad_cast + 0 4
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00000001f9b65120
>   default_unexpected_handler+ 8480 () + 0 5   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x00000001f9b7de48 _objc_terminate+ 28232 () + 124 6
>
>   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00000001f9b710fc
>   std::__terminate(void (*)+ 57596 ()) + 16 7   libc++abi.dylib
>
>     0x00000001f9b71188 std::terminate+ 57736 () + 84 8
>
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001fa3e8498
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 36 9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fa3b8260 _dispatch_once_callout + 28 10  Reflex
>
>     0x0000000100b5280c +[Fabric sharedSDK] + 112 11  Reflex
>
>     0x0000000100b52984 __15+[Fabric with:]_block_invoke + 76 12 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001fa3e8484
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 16 13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fa3b8260 _dispatch_once_callout + 28 14  Reflex
>
>     0x0000000100b52934 +[Fabric with:] + 224 15  Reflex
>
>     0x00000001009f3600 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1439232
>   (AppDelegate.m:64) 16  UIKitCore
>
>     0x0000000226f51564 -[UIApplication
>   _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 412 17  UIKitCore                        0x0000000226f52ccc -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3340 18  UIKitCore                         0x0000000226f58718 -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1552 19  UIKitCore                         0x000000022777f6dc __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability
>   _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 784 20  UIKitCore                       0x000000022777bc88 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160 21  UIKitCore                      0x000000022777f358
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240 22  UIKitCore                       0x000000022777fcf8
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1076 23  UIKitCore
>
>     0x000000022773ef20 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas
>   _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 772 24  UIKitCore                       0x000000022773ebcc -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432 25  UIKitCore                       0x0000000227782168
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 220 26  UIKitCore                       0x0000000227782c58 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112 27  UIKitCore                         0x0000000227782020 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 248 28  UIKitCore                       0x000000022777b334 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368 29  UIKitCore                       0x0000000226f56c10
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540 30 
>   UIKitCore                         0x0000000226f883c8
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364 31  FrontBoardServices
>     0x00000001fd3db890 -[FBSSceneImpl
>   _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444 32  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001fd3e6658 __56-[FBSWorkspace
>   client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 260 33 
>   FrontBoardServices                0x00000001fd3e5d50 __40-[FBSWorkspace
>   _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 64 34  libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001fa3e8484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 35 
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00000001fa3bf3f0
>   _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216 36  FrontBoardServices             0x00000001fd41a640
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 40 37  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001fd41a2cc -[FBSSerialQueue
>   _performNext] + 416 38  FrontBoardServices                0x00000001fd41a8e8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   56 39  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001fa93e5b8
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24 40  CoreFoundation                    0x00000001fa93e538 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
>   + 88 41  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001fa93de1c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176 42  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001fa938ce8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1040 43  CoreFoundation
>     0x00000001fa9385b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 44  GraphicsServices
>     0x00000001fcba8584 GSEventRunModal + 100 45  UIKitCore
>     0x0000000226f5a4c4 UIApplicationMain + 212 46  Reflex
>     0x0000000100a663d0 main + 1909712 (main.m:14) 47  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00000001fa3f8c0c start + 4

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug with Fabric and Xcode 10 beta 5 that prevents build on real device but you can build on simulator, Upgrade to Xcode 10 beta 6 and this bug should be fixed

Comment: Hmm, Fabric 2.7.2 still crashes on Xcode 10 GM. Building to iPhone X, iOS 12 GM, crashes when build completes.              Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: csymgenerator reply queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]